# Engineering in Kazakhstan and Rainfall Intensity

Tags: civil-engineering, hydrology

We are about to commence a large project in Astana, Kazakhstan worth several hundred million dollars. The design of Stormwater quantity, quality, and hydrology will be a large component of our works, and I am having an issue locating rainfall Intensity-Frequency-Duration (IFD) tables for the region. Similar to those which one might use from the Bureau of Meteorology on any site in Australia and are crucial to the design of stormwater.

My question is, has anyone completed drainage design for this region, or can anyone provide pointers on where I might find IFD tables for this region? More generally, does anyone have pointers on designing stormwater systems in freeze-thaw conditions.

Comment: Have you tried the Russian equivalent of the BoM for archival data from the Soviet era? It may also be worth asking western mining companies that have or have recently had large operations in Kazakhstan on who to contact about getting such data.

Comment: [Kazakhstan Institute for Meteorology](http://www.kazinmetr.kz/eng/) could be a place to start.